# Skipping alternate data points in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am using the following code to get a graph:

```
set term jpeg size "600,600"
set output "test2.jpeg"

unset key
set xtic 500
set ytic 100

set title "DD-ME2"
plot "nkBDDME2.out" us 2:1 lc -1 lw 2 with lines , "nkDDME2.out" us 2:1 lc rgb "#FF4433" pt 5 ps 0.5
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMsFy.jpg)

In the plot, the points are very close together making the other line less visible. Is there any way to plot alternate data points to space out the points? Is there any way of doing this without directly manipulating the data file by deleting the alternate data values?

Comment: Did you have a look at `help every`?

Comment: @Eldrad No. I did not know about that. After looking at it, my problem is solved. Thanks.